# Is it possible to reuse existing React components in ClojureScript Om app?

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, om

I have a lot of React components in my current project. Is it any way to reuse this components, if I decide to write next project in Om?

Comment: it seems, Reagent can reuse raw React components:  https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/src/reagent/core.cljs#L46

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  I created a Date Component that I have four instances of.  One is for selecting a Day and another is for selecting a Week.

So, when I create them, I pass in a map to configure them:

```
(om/build common/column-input-date {:component-id :selected-daily-date})
(om/build common/column-input-date {:component-id :selected-weekly-date})
(om/build common/column-input-date {:component-id :selected-monthly-date})
(om/build common/column-input-date {:component-id :selected-jobs-date})
```

Then in the component:

```
(defn column-input-date [data owner]
  "column input date"
    (reify
      om/IInitState
      (init-state [_]
                  {:e-map {:display (:display data)
                           :component-id (:component-id data)}})
      om/IDidMount
```

Beyond, the page, everything is a component, so I have about 20 components.  Mine communicate via core.async and get their data from ref-cursors. I tried passing data down the component tree and decided that was over-coupled.

Comment: Well, I don't have a problem to reuse *Om* component in Om app. The question is about reusing *React* components (writen in plain JavaScript React) in Om application.

Comment: I experimented with react when it first came out, so I took a look at my early code.  And from the looks of it, I don't think there is any reason why I couldn't utilize it.  After all, it is just JavaScript and Om compiles down to JavaScript.  My current React Components, written in Om, utilize core.async and ref-cursors, so sharing data might be an issue.